# Search spreadsheet by column value, return rows then post the content to external API: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, google-sheets-api

I am new to javascript/google app script and I'm trying to find the best script to complete a task. I've got a google sheet where I need to check values in certain columns, and depending on a matching case it returns that row data that are to be posted through external API. Then the response (Ideally a project come to be set back to a different column of the same row.

I am not sure the most efficient way to search through the specific columns and grabbing not just that value but the entire row and pass them to external API.

Here is what I tried but failed miserably. Someone who can help me craft the code will please rescue me here.

```
    function findTheLastRow(){
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
      var range = sheet.getRange("W2:W").getValues();
      var searchString = "0";
      if(searchString = "0")
      {
      var lastRow = lastRowData()
      var data = {

        'name':lastRow[2],
        'client': lastRow[3],
        'starts_at':lastRow[5],
        'ends_at':lastRow[6],
        'project_state':lastRow[4],

    };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'payload' : data,
    };
      var url = 'https:....';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var json = JSON.parse(response);
      var id = json ["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getLastRow() function [1] to narrow the array to have only cells with data. You have to take in account that getValues function [2] returns a 2D array every time. And you can use setValue function [3] to set the value on the cell with the match.

```
function findTheLastRow(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  var range = sheet.getRange("W2:W"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var searchString = "0";

  for (var i = 0; i<range.length; i++) {
    if(range[i][0] == searchString) {
      var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2+i,1,1,7).getValues(); //Assuming you only need 7 columns from each row
      var data = {

        'name':lastRow[0][2],
        'client': lastRow[0][3],
        'starts_at':lastRow[0][5],
        'ends_at':lastRow[0][6],
        'project_state':lastRow[0][4],

      };
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'payload' : data,
      };
      var url = 'https:....';
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var json = JSON.parse(response);
      var id = json["id"];
      //Assuming you want id value in 8th column
      sheet.getRange(2+i, 8).setValue(id);
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue

Comment: Hi @Andres, Thanks for coming through and giving me valuable insights. I have edited the column numbers so as to reflect my situation. Code runs well and gets the search results as expected, however, I am unable to get the data posted to the external API. Debugg shows no error or formatting issue. Could you advise further, please?

Comment: You mean you're not getting a response from the request?

Comment: Oh, shoot!, My bad. I did a mistake while numbering the rows. It works now. woow, You are the best @Andres.  One final question, what if I want on the response, the zero (0)--Search string to get updated to maybe 1, how do I go about it?

Comment: `searchString` variable is the one you need to change to the string you need, 1, etc.